# Rails 3 - CanCan error? NameError (uninitialized constant Ability::Invitation):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

**Error:**

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Ability::Invitation):
  app/models/ability.rb:72:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:12:in `new'
  app/controllers/invitations_controller.rb:12:in `current_ability'
  app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:14:in `call'
```

In CanCan i have:

```
can :manage, Invitation
```

in the Invitations Controller:

before_filter :current_ability  # CanCan
  load_and_authorize_resource #CanCan

def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user, nil)
  end

Application's controller:

```
#CanCan
def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user, nil) # since no group
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :invitations
```

Any thoughts why CanCan isn't happy? thanks

Answer (score 9):

Looks like you are trying to reference a class that is not defined. Is there a file at `app/models/invitation.rb` that defines this `Invitation` class?